# Div's percentage height not working as expected

Tags: html, css, height

I came up with a very strange behaviour. I created 3 divs with their height written in percentage. When i test them on their own page the behave as expected, but when i include them in another container they lose their height.

I think this happens because in the normal page the height is a percentage of the body, while on the container is a percentage of the parent div, but I can tell exactly what to do.

## HTML

```
<div id="mywrapper">
    <div class="box"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed nisi eget ligula egestas interdum vitae ornare metus. Quisque vitae sapien facilisis, sodales nibh in</p></div>
    <div class="box"><p>Maecenas placerat libero at lorem pretium, sed condimentum diam condimentum. In eu scelerisque tellus. Cras sollicitudin cursus arcu vitae lacinia. Fusce pellentesque maximus pulvinar. Duis placerat varius augue, at sagittis nisi bibendum ve</p></div>
    <div class="box"><p>urna viverra et.</p></div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

#mywrapper {
    background-color: #eee;
    min-height: 100%;
    height:auto !important;
    height:100%;            
    overflow: hidden !important; 
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
}

.box {
    z-index:10;         
    position:relative;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    height:45%;
    width:30%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
}

.box p {
    color:#fff;
}
```

## Normal Page

[image]

## Inside Container

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Their heights are becoming relative to the container. Thats why they aren't behaving as they were before.

Comment: Any tricks to have fluid height? I don't want to set the height on pixels

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider using display: table & display: table-cell for the parent and children, respectively. This way, the height of all 3 will be determined by the tallest cell.

```
#mywrapper {
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
}

.box {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: top;
width: 33.33%;
background: black;
}
```

To give the container a fixed height, just give the parent (#mywrapper) a height. The immediate children children (.box) that are display: table-cell, will take the height of the parent that is display: table.

Comment: But what if the heights needs to be fixed? Say no matter the size of the text inside, the div must be an exact number height